# My aiohttp requests dont work if there is a proxy set

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, aiohttp

This is the error im getting:

`aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientHttpProxyError: 403, message='Forbidden', url=URL('http://proxy:port')`

My proxy provider is `smartproxy.com`

The code is below:

```
import aiohttp, discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env = True) as session:
        async with session.get("https://www.google.com/", proxy="PROXY_URL") as res:
            print(res)


client.run(token)
```

Comment: did you check if other programs works with this proxy - ie. web browser? is this free proxy? Most free proxies are outdated and they don't work. Besides portals like `Google` has big money to create system which detect proxy and block access. They may have proxies on blacklists and block them because they are often used by spamers/hackers/bots.

Comment: @furas It's paid proxies, "smartproxy.com". I tried this on multiple different websites, including random IP APIs which would have no reason to block the IP. Still no luck.

Comment: some proxy providers have special offers with proxies only for accessing `Google Search` (usually named `SEO proxies`) because it has more money to build bigger system to catch bots/hackers

Comment: BTW: you could also check what data send your code - especially header `User-Agent` because it is first method to detect bots/script. I don't know what header is used by `aiohttp` but for example `requests` sends something like `Python/3.x Requests/2.x` and every server know that it is script. You could send request to https://httbin.org/get and it should send back JSON with your headers, cookies, form data, etc.

Comment: BTW: Google may also know many proxy servers and block them.